# php extract all objects from an array if value equals to a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects :

```
array (size=13)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '62' (length=2)
      'firstName' => string 'Alio' (length=24)
      'lastName' => string 'Djam' (length=7)
      'city' => string 'Paris' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'firstName' => string 'Jack' (length=7)
      'lastName' => string 'Jacky' (length=6)
      'city' => string 'Berlin' (length=8)
  ...
```

I need to extract all objects with city equals to a variable (Berlin, Paris, ...).

Comment: You don't have any objects here.

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried, and the results of that code, so we can see what you've tried that isn't working and narrow down the problem.

Comment: array_filter is the answer. Won't be able to help without code.

Comment: array_filter, iterative style foreach, array_map with a callback. 0 attempts ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$city = 'Berlin';
$found = [];
foreach($data as $row){
   if($row['city'] == $city){
       $found[] = $row;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Answers_Seeker said in a comment, you could use array_map function:

```
<?php

    $data = array(
      array('id' => '62', 'firstName' => 'Alio', 'lastName' => 'Djam', 'city' => 'Paris'),
      array('id' => '2', 'firstName' => 'Jack','lastName' =>'Jacky','city' => 'Berlin'),        
      );

      $res = [];

        function save_city($val){
            return $val['city'];
        }


      $res = array_map("save_city",$data);

      var_dump( $res );
?>
```